# List within a Do loop, I can't get any values

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

I am having the following problem. I am trying to get some values from solving an equation and apply them into a list but in the output I get nothing but the symbol of the variable...

The code is as follows:

```
alist = {1.158994747916576`*^-7, 1.3484818161772036`*^-7, 
  1.5672614729426443`*^-7, 1.8195986039943002`*^-7};

sumtrap = 500;
blist = {};

Do[

 temp = alist[[a]];
 NSolve[f == 1 - Exp[-sumtrap*temp], f];
 AppendTo[blist, f],
 {a, 1, 4}]
blist
```

> The Output is: {f, f, f, f}

Ommiting the `Do` loop results in:

```
temp = alist[[1]];
NSolve[f == 1 - Exp[-sumtrap*temp], f]
```

> The Output is: {{f -> 0.0000579481}}

Thank you for your time.

Comment: @m0nhawk - Looks like we pressed the edit button at the same time ^^

Comment: The first step of debugging a program is *to break it down to small pieces* and *test each piece individually*.  It looks like you wrote up a relatively large piece of code without any testing of its parts, and then ran it together.    Run `NSolve[f == 1 - Exp[-sumtrap* 1.15*^-7], f]` first.  What does it output?  Run `AppendTo[blist, f]`.  What happens?  What would you expect to happen?  `f` never gets a values here, it is a symbol with no assigned value.  It gets appended to `blist` as is.

Comment: @Kay It's "fastest edit" game, so... I'm winning. :)

Comment: See also: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12505 and https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/UseRuleSolutions.html and consider using `Table` instead of `Do`/`AppendTo`.

Comment: Thank you all, the Table helped alot!!!
Still having some issues but i think i can manage them!!!